# Using memorycache in asp.net mvc application it gets created everytime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, memorycache

```
Environment:
      asp.net mvc
      iis
```

I have create a wrapper and concrete class around memorycache  which in its **constrcutor** i set memoryCache

```
  public class AbijMemoryCache : IAbijMemoryCache
{
    private readonly MemoryCache _cache;

    public AbijMemoryCache()
    {
        if (_cache == null)
        {

            _cache = MemoryCache.Default;

        }
    }
}
```

then in **unity** for getting only one instance of memory cache I have used **ContainerControlledLifetimeManager**

```
  container.RegisterType<IAbijMemoryCache, AbijMemoryCache>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

i set cache in my homeController using following code

```
  var policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
  _cache.Set(key, value, policy);
```

but after uploading it to iis cache get empty sometime.

checking

```
        _cache.Get(key) **`it gets null`**
```

why its getting null?
what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that MemoryCache is working by reference so if you do assign an object to memoryCache it will 
be by refremce

```
  _cache.Set(key, value, policy); //value should not be an object.
```

you can use  a serialize before caching the value so it can be done like

```
 var cloneValue = SerializationCloner.DeepFieldClone(value);
```